# Retrieving attributes through rails join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 3 models: products, tags and products_tags:

Tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :products, :through => :products_tags
        has_many :products_tags
end
```

Product Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :through => :products_tags
  has_many :products_tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products_tags
```

Join:

```
class ProductsTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

I need a query which will retrieve the attributes related to the tag and the product model, as an AREL object.

So for example:

My tag table has 1 field: Cat_name 
My product table has: Title, URL, Image_url.

How can I retrieve all these attributes as an AREL record.

Comment: Do you have a starting point to limit your search query? For instance, a specific tag or tag_id?

Comment: Im not sure where I would start..I need to find all, as this is going to feed into an index for a "stats" page.

Comment: So you would essentially want data for all tags, for all products?  Can you provide an example of data you would want as a result?

Comment: Yea, and would like to group them by tag_name, just to avoid duplicated. So essentially I plan on having a table in my stats index, which basically lists all cat names and number of products associated with that specific cat name. The number of product would be a link to show details(title, urls) of the products belonging to that cat name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't state where you want to start your search from to retrieve this, so let's just go through all of them.

### Starting from tags

Specific tag and associated products as an ActiveRecord object:

```
Tag.find(params[:id], include: :products)
```

Specific tag and associated products as an arel object:

```
Tag.where(id: params[:id]).includes(:products)
```

All tags and associated products as an array of ActiveRecord objects:

```
Tag.includes(:products)
```

All tags and associated products as an arel object:

```
Tag.includes(:products).arel
```

### Starting from products

Specific product and associated tags as an ActiveRecord object:

```
Product.find(params[:id], include: :tags)
```

Specific product and associated tags as an arel object:

```
Product.where(id: params[:id]).includes(:tags)
```

All products and associated tags as an array of ActiveRecord objects:

```
Product.includes(:tags)
```

All products and associated tags as an arel object:

```
Product.includes(:tags).arel
```

Rails has an [excellent guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) that covers many to many associations and joins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

The following **join relationship**

```
 @producttag=Tag.find(:all,:joins => :Product ,:select => "*")

 @producttag
```

contain what you require

let me know your comments....